# Ajax success function  issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My javascript looks like that.

There are some problems that I can't figure out, where I did mistake

- `#status_message` doesn't show generated message
- `$("#status").className = 'fail';` doesn't override current class

[image]

```
var message=$("#status_message"), form=$("#bcscan"), ids=$('#itemids'),proctype, destination, counter=0, tenWordCounter = 0, autoPostInterval=null, errorcount=0, successcount=0;

function ajaxPost() {
    formData = form.serialize()+'&process=Scan';    
    formUrl = form.attr('action');
    formMethod = form.attr('method');

    $.ajax({
        url: formUrl,
        type: formMethod,
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) { 
            var now = new Date();
            if(data.err_detected==="yes")
            {     
                if(data.errors.indexOf(",") != -1)
                    errorcount=errorcount+data.errors.split(",").length;
                else errorcount=errorcount+1;                
                $("#status").className = 'fail';
                message =errorcount+" errors found";
                $('#errors').prepend(data.errors).slideDown("slow");                        
            }  
            $('#success').prepend(data.success).slideDown("slow");
            if(data.success.indexOf(",") != -1)
                successcount=successcount+data.errors.split(",").length;
            else successcount=successcount+1;              
            message +="Last submitted:"+now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
            $("#status_message").text(message); 
        }
    });   
}
```

[Here is page in action](http://tural.no-ip.org/?page=bcscan)

*If you want to test, please choose some option from selects like, output from db, ebay.fr and press "scan". Enter 10 digits seperated by comma try 41,42 (they exist in db tables) too between them. After 10th digit it will post textarea via ajax.*

Comment: I used firebug in Firefox and I think your ajaxPost() has not been called.

Comment: @SérgioMichels ajaxpost will be fire up ONLY after 10 value + ","

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the message, you've declared a jQuery object pointing at the element:

```
var message = $('#status_message'), ...
```

but then you're *overwriting* it with a string:

```
message = errorcount + ' errors found';
```

You should be calling:

```
message.text('some string...')
```

to change its contents.

For the class change, the correct syntax is:

```
$("#status").addClass('fail');
```

Comment: addClass('fail'); will override current class?

Comment: Fixed class issue, but still cannot fix message issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$('#status').attr('class','fail');
```

This will override the current class.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?? `$("#status").addClass( 'fail');`

Comment: addClass('fail'); will override current class?